# Periodicity of $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{\frac{5}{x}-\frac{1}{\cdots}}}$ and others

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

The function
$$f(x)=\frac{\color{blue}{1}}{x}-\frac{1}{\frac{\color{blue}{3}}{x}-\frac{1}{\frac{\color{blue}{5}}{x}-\frac{1}{\cdots}}}$$
is periodic with minimal period $\pi$.

But what if we replace the arithmetic sequence $(\color{blue}{1},\color{blue}{3},\color{blue}{5},\ldots)$ by another one?

Neither
$$g(x)=\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{x}-\frac{1}{\frac{\color{blue}{4}}{x}-\frac{1}{\frac{\color{blue}{6}}{x}-\frac{1}{\cdots}}},$$
nor
$$h(x)=\frac{\color{blue}{1}}{x}-\frac{1}{\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{x}-\frac{1}{\frac{\color{blue}{3}}{x}-\frac{1}{\cdots}}}$$
seem to be periodic.

In fact, I tried the arithmetic sequences $(3n+1)_{n=0}^\infty$, $(4n+1)_{n=0}^\infty$, $(4n+3)_{n=0}^\infty$, $(5n+1)_{n=0}^\infty$, with no apparent success: none of them seems to generate a non-constant periodic function here.

Is it true that, out of all positive integer arithmetic sequences, only $(2n+1)_{n=0}^\infty$ generates a non-constant periodic function in this context? If so, why?

**Remark:** $f$ is actually the cotangent function; see https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tan/10/0003/.

Comment: Function $g$ is obtained from the function $h$ by a linear substitution $x\mapsto x/2$.

Comment: @markvs What do you mean?

Comment: I have edited the comment.

Comment: $(4n+2)_n$ gives a periodic function, too, of course.

Comment: @markvs Why is that relevant?

Comment: If one of them is periodic then so is the other.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Are all these sequences of the form $(2nk+k)_n$?

Comment: @Eric Towers How come $g(x)=\cot (x/2)$? I don't think so.

Comment: $4/(2x)=2/x{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: So you do not agree that $g(x)=h(x/2)$?

Comment: @EricTowers: "@markvs 's comments point out that $g(x)=\cot(x/2)$". My comments point to nothing like that.

Comment: @markvs I agree that $g(x)=h(x/2)$; however, $g(x)\ne \cot (x/2)$.

Comment: Of course not: continued fraction for $\cot$ is here: https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/10/0001/

Comment: @markvs You can get the continued fraction from https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tan/10/0003/ as well, since $\cot x=\frac{1}{\tan x}$.

Answer (score 3):

The standard reference for continued fractions (at least as of 100 years ago) is

Perron, Oskar, *Die Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen*. Leipzig—Berlin: B. G. Teubner. xiii, 520 S. $(8^\circ)$ (1913). [ZBL43.0283.04](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:43.0283.04).

Section 81, Satz 3 states (in modern language): Consider the continued fraction
$$
b_0 + \frac{a_1}{b_1 + \displaystyle\frac{a_2}{b_2+\ddots}}
$$
with $a_n = a$ and $b_n = dn+c$.  Provided $a \ne 0, c \ne 0,$ and $d \ne 0$, the value of the continued fraction is
$$
V = \frac{c \; {}_0F_1(;c/d;a/d^2)}{\;{}_0F_1(;1+c/d;a/d^2)\;}
$$

---

Using this, we get:

$$
f(x) = \cot(x)
$$
which is periodic;

$$
g(x) = \frac{J_0(x)}{J_1(x)}
$$
in terms of Bessel functions, which is not periodic, and

$$
h(x) = \frac{J_0(2x)}{J_1(2x)}
$$
which is not periodic.

Comment: Did someone investigate the behavior of $V$? When exactly is it periodic?

Comment: Periodic in which variable?

Comment: In the variable which reduces it to the three functions $f(x),g(x),h(x)$.

Comment: A more modern book is https://www.morebooks.de/store/gb/book/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8/isbn/978-3-659-71263-0 . I do not know if it has been translated into any non-Russian language.

Comment: I guess it is not periodic unless $c/d = \pm 1/2$, and then it reduces to a trig function.